# How to call a function, If Boolean is true in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here i wrote a popup function and one Boolean flag is their in my component class. My flag will return true or false based on my conditions. In template class popup function needs to fire when flag becomes true, then immediately my popup dialog box will come. But i am not aware to call right approach, If any one knows please help me the correct approach.

```html
<ng-template #sessionSuccessModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
 <div class="modal-header">
   <h4 class="modal-title">Include Criteria Error</h4>
   <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModel()">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body"  class="bg-light text-dark">
   <p>{{ alertMessage }}!</p>
 </div>
 <div style="text-align: center" class="bg-light text-dark">
   <button type="button"  (click)="closeModel()">Ok</button>
 
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

intially commaSeparation will be false, this.commaSeparation = this.genericValidator.validateMultiComma(this.orderUnitForm); this function is returning either true or false. If it is true then i need to call my displayModel() alert method. Now popup is working fine, calling in ngAfterViewInit() but getting error in console like.

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'

```js
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        let controlBlurs: Observable<any>[] = this.formControls
            .map((formControl: ElementRef) => Observable.fromEvent(formControl.nativeElement, 'blur'));
// debounceTime(1000)/
        Observable.merge(this.orderUnitForm.valueChanges, ...controlBlurs).subscribe(value => {
            this.displayMessage = this.genericValidator.processMessages(this.orderUnitForm);
           // this.valid = this.genericValidator.validateControls(this.orderUnitForm);
        });
        this.orderUnitForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(1000).subscribe(value => {
            this.valid = this.genericValidator.validateControls(this.orderUnitForm);
            this.commaSeparation = this.genericValidator.validateMultiComma(this.orderUnitForm);
              if(this.commaSeparation == true){
                this.displayModel();
              }
        });
  }
```

This is my dispalyModel() function:

```js
displayModel() {
     this.alertMessage = 'You cannot enter more than one multiple at the same time ';
     this.successErrorModalBlock = this.modalService.open(this.sessionSuccessModalref);
   }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) about the _ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError_. And please post your template as well. You can probably rely on reactivity to show your popup, i.e. something like `<popup *ngIf="commaSeparation">...</popup>` in your template will render `popup` whenever `commaSeparation` is true.

Comment: @FK82 No, I have changed that. now i am not using *ngIf in template, you can look that also. Now alert is coming fine but getting error, i am going through that article which you provided.

Comment: Are you using any of the class properties you set in the `subscribe` handlers in your template (i.e. `displayMessage`, `valid`, `commaSeparation`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this implementing the interface OnChanges that is a lifecycle hook of the Angular.

```
import { Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges  {

  // the flag property
  commaSeparation: boolean;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if (changes['commaSeparation'] && changes['commaSeparation'].currentValue){
        this.showPopup();
    }
  }

  public showPopup(){
        alert('Replace this alert by the code that shows your popup');
  }
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Comment: OP wants to the popup to be shown when `commaSeparation` becomes true. Your solution will always show it after view init.

Comment: @Rodrigo Thank you so much for your response, but i have tried this my popup is not coming. Basically my 'commaSeparation'  getting changed in 'ngAfterViewInit()'.

Comment: @Rodrigo But i called in 'ngAfterViewInit()' it self,like if(this.commaSeparation == true){
                this.displayModel();
              }, this is working fine but chrome console getting one error

Comment: @Royal, the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error will probably occur in development mode and not in production mode of Angular app. The detailed error message should say something about that. If you are not confortable with this, you can try some workarround solution described in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a bad idea to call functions with side effects inside an angular expression. Angular is free to call those functions however often it likes to make sure the result is still the same. You should use functions in these expressions to return a result, not to cause an action.

I would suggest instead calling popupAlert from your controller, e.g.

```
$scope.$watch('commaSeparation', function(commaSeparation) {
        // The value of commaSeparation has just changed. Alert if it changed to true!
        if (commaSeparation) {
            popupAlert();
        }
    });
```

Comment: OP not using angularjs (v 1.x) using angular 2+

Answer (score 0):

If `commaSeparated` is an input property, you can add a property change **watcher** using the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook and then call `popupAlert` if `commaSeparation` was changed ([link to docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)).

```
@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {

  // ...

  @Input()
  commaSeparation = false;

  // ...

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const commaSeparationChanges = changes.commaSeparation;

    if (commaSeparationChanges && commaSeparationChanges.currentValue) {
      this.popupAlert();
    }
  }
}
```

If `commaSeparated` is only changed inside the component, then you can just make it private and work with a getter/setter pair to trigger the popup:

```
@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {

  // ...

  private _commaSeparation = false;

  // ...

  get commaSeparation() {
    return this._commaSeparation;
  }

  set commaSeparation(value) {
    this._commaSeparation = value;

    if (value) {
       this.popupAlert();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but i have tried this my popup is not coming. Basically my 'commaSeparation' getting changed in 'ngAfterViewInit()'

Comment: You probably should post your code now. We need to know how `commaSeparation` is being changed.

Comment: intially commaSeparation will be false, this.commaSeparation = this.genericValidator.validateMultiComma(this.orderUnitForm); this function is returning either true or false. If it is true then i need to call my popup() alert method.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your component (template, controller)? There are a couple of potential reasons why you don't see the popup.

Comment: Updated, Please look at once.